Формат адреса в ответе yandex geocoder
Имеет ли Yandex API возможность указания форматирования возвращаемого адреса?
Например, Яндекс возвращает Московская область, Химки, Ленина улица, 1, а хотелось бы Московская обл., г. Химки, ул. Ленина, 1.
Если нет, есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки форматирования адресов для .NET?
Это можно было бы решить всё регулярками и пр., но тогда придется учесть всё - города, поселки, улицы, деревни и т. д. Довольно большой объем того, что API может вернуть.
UPD:
Как вариант, можно действительно просто учесть все виды муниципальных образований, которые используются на Яндекс-картах. Где можно получить такой список?

С адресами всё очень сложно: У семи программистов адрес без дома. И комментарии почитайте. Поэтому вряд ли можно автоматически всё правильно сформатировать.
